# Rotate Proxies using Webclient in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, proxy, webclient

Im using threads to make API Requests with Webclient and I want to roatate proxies with every request. I've seen multiple examples using Resttemplate but cannot find one with Webclient.

This function uses the Webclient:

```
public BigDecimal call() throws Exception {
    String proxyServer = getNextProxy();
    InetSocketAddress proxyAddress = new InetSocketAddress(proxyServer, 8080);  // Adjust port as needed
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxyAddress);

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();

    BigDecimal priceAvg = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    int goodsId = goodsList.stream().filter(good -> good.getName().equals(item.getMarket_hash_name())).findFirst().get().getId();
    log.info("Accessing API Endpoint");
    String apiUrl = "--url--";
    Mono<String> responseEntity = webClient.get()
            .uri(buff163Api + goodsId)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
}
```

Keep in mind, I have no clue about Proxies with Webclient, the first three lines of code are from ChatGPT.

Any help or useful resources would be very appreciated.